# splrep only taking into account upper points?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have data that is taken at different times and slightly different locations, and so high and low points form a "channel". I'm trying to find the average line of these points, so basically what's in the middle of the "channel"

Using a simple 5 order polynomial fit (`numpy.polyfit(x,y,5)`), I get the following result, where the fit goes right down the middle of the "channel" formed by the two data points (so the red line is smack in the middle of the blue points.
[image: Polyfit attempt]

The only issue is that I'm excluding a fairly crucial data point form this poly fit as it messes up everything (this is fluid flow in a pipe of radius=1. I'm excluding the [no-slip point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-slip_condition), which would be `(1,0)`, and really messes up the fit).

To try and sort this, I tried to use a spline fit (`scipy.interpolate.splrep`). However, after playing around with it for awhile, it seems to only care about the upper values of the "channel" up until around x=0.8:
[image: spline fit 1]

^This is without any setting changes (so just `splrep(x,y)`)
[image: spline fit 2]

^This is specifying some of the knots (`splrep(x,y,t=knots`)
[image: spline fit 3]

^This is specifying the smoothness (`splrep(x,y,s=5)`)

Adding in the "no-slip point" to the data does give the desired effect (ie. map the high velocity data the same, but still map the boundary layer down to the wall), but we still have the other issues:
[image: spline fit with no-slip point]

Is this normal behavior for the spline representation function? How do I make it take into account both the high and low point data?

Note: the "File Points" in the figures is just the spline being evaluated at specific points. Feel free to ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I didn't have my data in least->greatest order. The `splrep` function was only taking into account half of the data due to the order it was in when I imported it from csv.

So the data was organized as:

```
          r          V
0   0.92429  131.53931
1   0.88794  138.36454
2   0.83497  143.48595
3   0.75709  145.97411
4   0.69744  147.68532
5   0.63446  149.08677
6   0.56649  149.71351
7   0.51182  152.04439
8   0.45214  152.98041
9   0.38584  153.91706
10  0.25822  156.72013
11  0.13891  160.14254
12  0.01124  160.30995
13  0.11973  161.09784
14  0.26564  160.64686
15  0.36184  158.64068
16  0.42159  155.70073
17  0.49953  154.93309
18  0.55924  153.54353
19  0.61233  151.99828
20  0.67537  149.98889
21  0.74504  148.13517
22  0.80649  142.71477
23  0.88122  136.05535
0   1.00000    0.00000
```

So it was only taking into account data points 0->12. Once I changed that, the resulting spline then was applied to all the data:

[image]

The fit is still rough, but now I at least have a starting point.

Edit: Here's the result after some smoothing. Notice that the spline function actually passes between points now:

[image: Smoothed spline]